# Who Takes The Trick In Rage If Everyone Plays A Black Card?

Tags: rage

We've often had it happen that when playing rage, no one plays a "suit" card.  First player plays "Change Rage", second player plays "Out Rage" etc. etc.

In this case is there a rule as to who takes the trick?  Would it be the first player or would the trick simply be set aside and not count towards anyone's total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official rules](http://www.boardgamecapital.com/game_rules/rage.pdf) (see p. 3):

> The first color or Wild Rage card played will determine the lead suit of the trick.  **If only Action cards, not including Wild Rage, are played, the first card played in the round wins the trick.**